Migrate Azure Storage from LRS to ZRS
may I know the reason why I cannot migrate Azure Storage Account from LRS to ZRS. We are in West Europe and some of our Storage have no issues migrating from LRS to ZRS on the same region which is West Europe. The last time I changed the Redundancy of the Storage Account with issue is 1 week ago, so it should allow migration. The error the keep prompting is Moving LRS to ZRS is not available in the West Europe Region. It seemed weird that it work on some of the Storage Account while some doesn't Work. All Storage we have are already StorageV2. Any clue on this issue. Thank you
Tried using portal and poweershell but still yielding a not available ZRS in West Europe

What is the kind (Storage, Premium Storage, Block Blob Storage etc.) of storage account you are trying to migrate?

Hi @GauravMantri,  we are only using block blobs and in Standard V2 account

the official documentation currently says that customer initiated migration from LRS to ZRS is not supported in West Europe region.
Maybe Azure support can initiate a migration since ZRS is generally available if you create a new storage account.
Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/redundancy-migration?tabs=portal#region
